# C program crashing upon first inputs

Tags: c, crash

I'm having a problem with a C program crashing upon the first user input. It should be right, I think; the problem I'm having is that in runs properly with no errors given, but as soon as you give the first input, it just immediately crashes. Any ideas?

```
# define DOUGH_PER_SQFT 0.75
# define INCHES_PER_FEET 12
# define PI 3.141592654

# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>

int main() {

    // Get user inputs.

    int small, medium, large;

    printf("What is the radius of your small pizza, in inches?\n");
    scanf("%d", small);
    printf("What is the radius of your medium pizza, in inches?\n");
    scanf("%d", medium);
    printf("What is the radius of your large pizza, in inches?\n");
    scanf("%d", large);

    int smallfeet, mediumfeet, largefeet;

    smallfeet = ("%d/12", small);
    mediumfeet = ("%d/12", medium);
    largefeet = ("%d/12", large);

    // Find the amount of dough, in pounds, that will need to be ordered

    int surface_small, surface_medium, surface_large;

    surface_small = (PI*pow(smallfeet,2));
    surface_medium = (PI*pow(mediumfeet,2));
    surface_large = (PI*pow(largefeet,2));

    int smallweight, medweight, largeweight, doughneeded;

    smallweight = surface_small*DOUGH_PER_SQFT;
    medweight = surface_medium*DOUGH_PER_SQFT;
    largeweight = surface_large*DOUGH_PER_SQFT;

    int dough_for_smalls, dough_for_mediums, dough_for_larges, dough_needed;

    dough_for_smalls = smallweight*small;
    dough_for_mediums = medweight*medium;
    dough_for_larges = largeweight*large;
    dough_needed = dough_for_smalls + dough_for_mediums + dough_for_larges;

    // Find the answer.

    printf("You will need to buy ",dough_needed,"pounds of dough for this week");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose behind statements like, ` smallfeet = ("%d/12", small)`? And `printf("You will need to buy ",dough_needed,"pounds of dough for this week");` will not print the value of `dough_needed`. You really should read a C book or tutorial.

Comment: I think you would benefit if you sat down and read [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). It’s short and easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the address of the variable for `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &small);
```

Similarly others

Comment: Wow. I really suck. You're the best

Comment: One last thing - at this point, it's taking the user inputs for size, but then performing no calculations. It's going straight to the final printf, but since it didn't perform any calculations, it's just blank.

Comment: @JordanBarden Study about [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/1870232), every places you're using it wrongly. Turn on warnings while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
scanf("%d", small); //and
scanf("%d", medium); //and
scanf("%d", large);
```

To

```
scanf("%d", &small); //and
scanf("%d", &medium); //and
scanf("%d", &large);
```

This is done because the `%d` format specifier in `scanf` expects an `int*`, but you provide an `int` which caused the crash.

There are also other problems in the code. To fix them, change

```
smallfeet = ("%d/12", small);
mediumfeet = ("%d/12", medium);
largefeet = ("%d/12", large);
```

To

```
smallfeet = small/12;
mediumfeet = medium/12";
largefeet = large/12;
```

And

```
printf("You will need to buy ",dough_needed,"pounds of dough for this week");
```

To

```
printf("You will need to buy %d pounds of dough for this week",dough_needed);
```